# Are House and Senate "debates" pointless, aside from some PR value?

Tags: united-states, congress, legislative-process

I watch the House and Senate "debate" periods on bills and wonder who they are talking to and what is the point, aside from the later video clips. Has any Senator or Representative ever cared or even listened to what the "other" side is saying? Or are these times just particularly divisive?

In short, is it all (and always) just some sort of weird Kabuki theater?

Comment: Ever? Absolutely. Today, or in the recent past – that's a harder question. Are you interested in the historical question (ie, are there recorded instances of true debate in the US Congress?) or are you more interested about today where it does seem to resemble theater?